# URL Security in CodeIgniter Application

Tags: php, database, security, codeigniter

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to web development.

**Scenario**: I've built an application using CodeIgniter that would be best described as an event calendar. There is a shared feature in the application that allows you to share your event calendar with another individual. When logged in, a user can travel to the shared page, and choose from a list of those who have shared their event calendars with them. Currently, when a user selects the name of the person who has shared their event calendar with them, the following URI is generated:

```
http://example.com/folder/controller/method/id
```

The `id` section is the the `owner_id` in the database of the user who has shared their calendar with the individual.

**Issue**: It's easy to go change the `id` section of the URL to another user's `owner_id` in the database. This allows whoever does so to access the event calendar of an individual who has not authorized the sharing of their event calendar.

**Question**: What are some methods to resolve this security gap? Please let me know if there is anything else that I need to provide, or explain in a clearer fashion. Thanks in advance for your time and energy.

**Model**:

```
class Shares_model extends crud_model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->pk = 'id';
        $this->table_name = 'shares';
    }

    public function get($shared_to_user_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('shared_to_id', $shared_to_user_id);
        $ids = parent::get_all();

        $users = array();

        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            $users[$id->owner_id]['owner_id'] = $id->owner_id;
            $users[$id->owner_id]['owner_first_name'] = $id->owner_first_name;
            $users[$id->owner_id]['owner_last_name'] = $id->owner_last_name;
        }

        return $users;
    }   
}
```

**View**:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h4>Shared Planners</h4>
        <ol>
            <?php foreach($sharers as $s): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/shared/view/'.$s['owner_id']) ?>"><strong><?php echo $s['owner_first_name']." ".$s['owner_last_name'] ?></strong></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
class Shared extends Common_Auth_Controller {

    private $end_user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->end_user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['end_user'] = $this->end_user;
        $this->load->vars($data);

        $this->load->model('events_model', 'events');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $title['title'] = 'Shared';

        $this->load->model('shares_model','shares');

        $data['sharers'] = $this->shares->get($this->end_user->id);

        $this->load->view('public/head_view', $title);
        $this->load->view('user/header_view');
        $this->load->view('user/shared_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer_view');
    }
```

Comment: why have a table of authorizations for your events/calendars...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below logic

```
 <?php
            // Check if user is logged in 
            if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
            {
                //Not logged in , so redirect them to login page
                redirect('account/login', 'refresh');
            }

            else{
            // So the user is logged in 
            // Get the id of the currently logged in user ( The user who is trying to view the page )
            $current_user = $this->ion_auth->get_user();
            $current_userid = $current_user->id;


            // you need an array of users who have been invited to that event by the event creator
            // As you mentioned you are storing the users who have been invited in db, get the ids to an array 

            $invited_users = getIdsOfusers();

            if (in_array($current_userid, $invited_users)) {
                // Yes, The user who is trying to view the page has access
                // you can show him the respective view
            }
            else {
                // No, The user who is trying to view the page Doesn't have  access
                show_error('You dont have access !' ,500 );
            }
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is where access rights come in. Basically before loading up the page, do a check from your table to see if user (owner_id) has actually shared with the user who is browsing. If not, just display an error message or else display as normal .

Answer (score 1):

You could have a table that keeps track of all the calendars that a user can access. Then the first thing you do when a user attempts to access a calendar, is check if they are allowed to be viewing that.

Comment: The database already associates who owns the calendar, and who is authorized to view that calendar. I'm needing code that either can either authenticate this process, or secure the URL to prevent another user's calendar from being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You could secure the url by using 
[CodeIgniters Encryption-Library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you wish the logged in user is the only to see his calender, then you don't need to pass the id through url. Just take the user's id from session, and use that id to fetch the calender data.

And if you want any authorized / logged user to see calender of any user, you can simply check, whether he / she is logged in, or not. If not logged in, the use `redirect()` to redirect to an error page.

And for invited user check, just fetch the invited users' id from database, and use `in_array()` to check if the particular logged in user is invited or not, then redirect as you want...

Answer (score 1):

There are two stages of ensuring proper access to a page in a secure system.

1. Authentication - You must determine that the user IS who they SAY they are. This is usually performed using cookies to ensure that the one they sent matches the session of a logged in user. This cookie would be one you generated when they first logged in, and stored a copy of the token in the database. Every time a user requests a page, you make a check to ensure the current PHP SESSION belongs to a logged-in user and that they are still logged in.
2. Authorisation - Determine the AUTHENTICATED user is actually ALLOWED to view what they are trying to view. It's all well and good to know the person is truly who they say they are, but that doesn't mean average Joe gets access to the WHOLE government database when he should only see what is his. This is the key part of your problem - does the ID passed in the URI actually belong to the **authenticated** user? If so, display it. Otherwise, your good friend 403 is on standby.

There are resources on the CodeIgniter forum on setting up an authentication/authorisation system available as plugins.